# Reference error probably due to dependency issue in Javascript using require()

Tags: javascript, dependencies, browserify, require

I am using browserify in gulp in order to use the require() function. From there I am attempting to load a JS library using require before a script that refers to an object from the library.

```
require('tippy.js');

new Tippy(".tippy", {
    position: 'right',
    animation: 'scale',
    duration: 1000,
    arrow: true
});
```

When compiled and loaded in the browser I get this reference error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Tippy is not defined

I'm assuming it's a dependency issue. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
var Tippy = require('tippy.js');
```

Also, given that you're using a module system, I would suggest against relying on globals. Tippy is bundled as a [UMD module](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs/blob/master/dist/tippy.js#L8). It's packaged to detect the module system used by the environment and export the library accordingly. Since browserify is CJS, a UMD-bundled module returns a reference to the library's export from `require` and not load it to the global scope.

Comment: No. Is that what I need to do?

Comment: Worked. What do I need to study in order to better understand this? Researching how to use the "require()" function produces a wide scope of results.

Answer (score 0):

you should append it to Window variable like this :

```
window.Tippy = require('tippy.js').default;
```

then yo can use

```
Tippy(".tippy", {
position: 'right',
animation: 'scale',
duration: 1000,
arrow: true })
```